# $route.reload(); Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi im currenty using $route.reload to refresh the content of my controller Every time I update my Database. the problem is when updating huge list of data, Every Time I update my Database and run $route.reload my browser lose its ability to scroll up or down my browser, it works fine with smaller list of Data.

below is a sample of my code

```
$scope.Undone = function(id){
    $scope.index =  $scope.GetID ;

    CRUD.put('/UndoJda/'+$scope.index).then(function(response){         
            toastr.info('Jda has been activated.', 'Information');
    $route.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: How about reloading after a particular delay when data is huge?

Comment: I havent tried that but ill go give it a shot

Comment: your solution totally worked !! thx alot!

Answer (score 1):

When the data is huge, try to use `$timeout` and reload the page.

This would prevent very fast refreshes and will keep your page responsive.

```
$scope.Undone = function(id){
    $scope.index =  $scope.GetID ;

    CRUD.put('/UndoJda/'+$scope.index).then(function(response){         
        toastr.info('Jda has been activated.', 'Information');
        $timeout(function() {
          $route.reload();
        }, 200);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be some sort of lazy loading/pagination. So in case it's a really large list, like in the tenths of thousands, it might even be a DOM rendering problem. Also, if that isn't the case, you should try using AngularJS's bind once(Available since 1.3), as well as track by which does not create a watcher for each object on the scope, in your template. Assuming you are using ngRepeat, let's say something like this:

```
...<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in Items">
      <b>{{item.name}}</b>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Change that to something like the following, in case the data does not update often:

```
...<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in Items track by $index">
      <b>{{::item.name}}</b>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

As a side note, try to always have a dot in your model's name. $scope.Something.list, for eaxample. ("If you don't have a dot, you are doing it wrong" - Misko Hevery himself said this.).

Answer (score 1):

You can  do it by using `$interval`

```
 $interval(function() {
     CRUD.put('/UndoJda/'+$scope.index).then(function(response){         
        toastr.info('Jda has been activated.', 'Information');  
        // Update scope variable 
      });
    }, 2000);
```

and also don't use `$route.reload();`. because Angularjs supporting **SPA** (Single Page Application). if you using `$route.reload();`. Every time page will loading, So it's not good. you need just call the `Service code` in inside of interval.

Comment: Could you be more specific about using it in `$http`

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend removing usage of $route.reload(), your use case doesn't require the view re-instantiating the controller. Instead you should update the $scope variable that holds the collection of entities your presenting in the view. You will also want to consider adding UX features such as a loading indicator to inform the user about the long running task.

Something similar too the code below would achieve what your looking for. I am unaware of what your CRUD js object instance is, but as long as its Angular aware you will not need to use $timeout. Angular aware usually means non third party APIs, but you can use $q to assist in exposing third party ajax results to angular.

```
// angular module.controller()
function Controller($scope, EntityService) {
    $scope.entityCollection = [];
    $scope.loadingData = false; // used for loading indicator 

    // Something will initialize the entity collection
    // this is however your already getting the entity collection
    function initController() {
        $scope.refreshCollection();
    }

    initController();

    $scope.refreshCollection = function() {
        $scope.loadingData = true;

        EntityService.getEntitites().then(function(resp) {
            $scope.entityCollection = resp;

            $scope.loadingData = false;
        });
    }

    $scope.Undone = function(id) {
        $scope.index =  $scope.GetID ;

        CRUD.put('/UndoJda/' + $scope.index).then(function(response){         
            toastr.info('Jda has been activated.', 'Information');

            $scope.refreshCollection();
        });
    }
}

// angular module.factory()
function EntityService($q, $http) {
    return {
        getEntitites: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.post('/some/service/endpoint').then(function(resp) {
                deferred.resolve(resp);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already did something close to this, I had issues so I decided to use  $route.reload instead.

Comment: @BananaTiger Could you provide any details about the issues you ran into? I think in the long run you may find $route.reload to be problematic depending on what your doing in your UI.